# YUI Compressor on entire directory - os x

Tags: macos, terminal, minify, yui-compressor

I am trying to figure out how to run yui compressor on an entire directory.  I want to compress the directory to another directory named compressed.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming current working directory in a terminal contains these three:

- css/
- compressed/
- yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar

Run this command:

```
for i in `ls css`; do java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar -o compressed/$i css/$i; done;
```

Note this does not work recursively.